# AmCharts4: Exporting menu doesn't provide options for CSV, XLSX and JSON

Tags: angular, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm using AmCharts4 and I want to export chart data in CSV, XLSX and JSON format.

I'm including the following scripts in index.html:
`<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>`
`<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>`

in .ts file:
...
`import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";`
...
`let chart4 = am4core.create("chartdiv4", am4charts.XYChart);`
`chart4.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();`

and I'm not getting all the options for data export:
[options that are provided are HTML and PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKrXU.png)

What can cause this?

Thanks,
Biljana

Comment: It must be related to specific chart setup. Try setting up a working demo on codesandbox or stackblitz.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve this.

The chart's data property needs to be populated and **after that** you will need to assign an instance of `ExportMenu` to the chart's `exporting.menu` property.

If data happens to be empty, equal to `[]`, then the Data menu item of the exporting menu will be missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have data in individual series and no data assigned to the whole chart, you can use an adapter to combine the data from the series. They have a tutorial [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/combining-local-data-from-multiple-series-for-export/) that shows you how to do it.