# amcharts4 export menu not displaying all options

Tags: amcharts4

this is a duplicate from "[AmCharts4: Exporting menu doesn't provide options for CSV, XLSX and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308511/amcharts4-exporting-menu-doesnt-provide-options-for-csv-xlsx-and-json?newreg=7a82f081d4ac4b359e71f8b84c1d2479)", but as I'm new, I can't comment on his question (unanswered yet).

So here is a stackblitz with the same issue : https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ewqn6f .

The problem is that the export menu provided by Amcharts4 doesn't display all the export options.

The amcharts4 documentation (https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/exporting/) doesn't mention any sort of additional imports needed, so I do not understand what I need to do in order to unlock the "Data" exports.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Data must be present in your chart in order for the export menu to show any data-oriented export options.

Comment: I updated the stackblitz, having data didn't bring out the export data options.

Comment: I've thought about your comment again, and I added data directly to the "chart.data" object, and the export option did appear. The origin of my problem was that I added data to the "series.data" object but not to the "chart.data" object. Thanks a lot, now I need to understand how to adequately add data from multiple series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AmCharts' export functionality looks in the chart's data array to determine whether to show the data export or not. If you only have series-level data, you'll want to use a `data` adapter on the chart's exporting object to consolidate everything, for example:

```
chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();
chart.exporting.adapter.add("data", function(data, target) {
  // Assemble data from series
  var data = [];
  chart.series.each(function(series) {
    for(var i = 0; i < series.data.length; i++) {
      series.data[i].name = series.name;
      data.push(series.data[i]);
    }
  });
  return { data: data };
});
```

There's a demo of this in [the documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/combining-local-data-from-multiple-series-for-export/)

Comment: It works fine. I didn't see the "data" adapter in the ExportMenu documentation though. (https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/exportmenu/#Adapters) How is that so ?

Comment: Because it belongs to the *Export* class (https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/export/#data_adapter), not ExportMenu.